# PushSharp - How to trigger OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, pushsharp

I have standard pushsharp code that looks like the following

```
  PushBroker push = new PushBroker();

  var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(@"myp12.p12");

   push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
   push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
   push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
   push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
   push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
   push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated; 
   push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

   push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, appleCert, "password"));


   push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                       .ForDeviceToken(mydevice)
                       .WithAlert("hello world")
                       .WithBadge(1)
                       .WithSound("default")
                       .WithCategory("INVITE_CATEGORY")
                       .WithCustomItem("custom-item", "i'm so cool"));


   push.StopAllServices();
```

I can send push notifications just fine. The appropriate events get called at the correct times.

What I want to test is the logic that would take place when Apple tells me this particular subscription has expired. I attached the event, but I cannot seem to have it get called. It looks more or less like this

```
static void DeviceSubscriptionExpired(object sender, string expiredDeviceSubscriptionId, DateTime timestamp, INotification notification)
    {
       //logic that deactivates subscription in database
    }
```

How can I trigger this event?

I thought I could just delete the app, and then try sending multiple notifications to this device. But this doesn't seem to be working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this event is available for iOS. In the two years I've been working with PushSharp the only event returned from Apple is ServiceException. But from Google I've received DeviceSubscriptionExpired and DeviceSubscriptionChanged.

Comment: Correct, this event is not available using APNS currently.  It will be available once the HTTP/2 APNS provider API implementation is complete in PushSharp 3.x.